# Writing blank columns to CSV from Pyspark dataframe but the columns aren't actually blank and it can be seen in pyspark-shell

Tags: pyspark

Spark dataframes are written empty, but I can see the data in shell.

Please find the code below:

```
df1_unoperated_columns = [x for x in df1.columns if x not in non_descriptive_List]
df2 = df1.withColumn("unoperated_list",array(df1_unoperated_columns).cast('array<string>'))
df3 = df2.withColumn('non_descriptive_List',array(non_descriptive_List).cast('array<string>'))
df4_columns = non_descriptive_List + ['unoperated_list','non_descriptive_List']
df4 = df3.selectExpr(df4_columns)
df5 = df4.select(*((when(isnull(col(c)), '0').otherwise('1')).alias(c + '_YN') if (dict(df4.dtypes)[c] != 'array<string>') else col(c) for c in df4.columns))
df6 = df5.withColumn('non_descriptive_List',col('non_descriptive_List').cast('array<double>'))
df7 = df6.select(['*']+[col('unoperated_list')[i].alias(j).cast('string') for i,j in enumerate(df1_unoperated_columns)]+[col('non_descriptive_List')[i].alias(j).cast('double') for i,j in enumerate(non_descriptive_List)]).drop('unoperated_list').drop('non_descriptive_List')
df7.write.mode('overwrite').option('header',True).csv('abc.csv')
```

Comment: can you post some your code to understand problem ?

Comment: Thanks for looking out arjun, I have posted main part of code